# How to add category filter with OR condition in product collection?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, product-collection, category-products

I'm using magento v2.4.1 and i have a custom attribute name landmark, and i want to filter a product collection using landmark attribute and category id using OR condition. Currently i'm doing it like below, but the problem is, it always running AND filter:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('landmark', array('eq' => $landmark));
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in'=>$categoryId]);
```

How can i merge these two filters into OR condition ?